# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component without useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hello guys I have a basic component that takes product info and render it. It has a method called `onAaddToWishList` which takes product id, fetches the data from API and adds it to my wishlist.

```
const Product = (props) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const onAddToWishlist = (e, id) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!loading) {
            setLoading(true)

            instance.get(`/products/product/${id}`, {
                headers: {
                    'X-Auth-Token': findToken()
                }
            })
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.data.food) {
                        alert('Product added')

                        props.addToWishlist(response.data.food);

                        console.log(response.data.food)
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Product not found')
                    }

                    setLoading(false);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)

                    setLoading(false);

                    alert('Error occured.try again')
                })
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="ProductCard">
            <div className="ProductCard--Image">
                <img src={props.image} alt="iclereu" />
            </div>
            <div className="ProductCard--Container">
                <h1>{props.title}</h1>
                <p>{props.description}</p>
                <span>&#8380; {props.price}</span>
                <div className="ProductCard--Nav">
                    <div className="ProductCard--Link">
                        <Link to="/">View more</Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="ProductCard--Link">
                        <a
                            onClick={(e) => onAddToWishlist(e, props.id)}
                            href="#"
                        >
                            {!loading ? "+Wishlist" : "Loading..."}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        wishlist: state.wishlist
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addToWishlist: (product) => dispatch(wishlistActions.addToWishList(product))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Product)
```

This is my `addToWishList` action:

```
const addToWishList = (product) => {
    return dispatch => {
        let wishlist = [...store.getState().wishlist];
        let exists = wishlist.find(prod => prod.product._id === product._id);

        if (!exists) {
            wishlist = [...wishlist, {
                product: product,
                count: 1
            }]
        }
        else {
            let index = wishlist.findIndex(prod => prod.product._id === product._id);
            wishlist[index].count++;
        }

        dispatch({ type: "ADD_TO_WISHLIST", wishlist: wishlist })
    }
}
```

`props.addToWishlist` is function for **redux** action(it saves data to redux store(`wishlist`)). Problem is whatever I do inside this action I get the following warning:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

But I don't use `useEffect` hook. It works actually(it adds a product to `wishlist`) but the warning is pretty annoying like I do something wrong. Even I console the argument of the redux action it gives the same error. I would be grateful if someone helps me

Comment: can you show the wishlist component?

Comment: what do you mean by a wishlist component? error occurs when data is saved to the redux wishlist

Comment: I am thinking that the issue is outside this component... Maybe the parent component of this One or maybe some other component depending on wishlist state

Comment: by the way you action should be much simpler and the logic should be on the reducer.
and you are mutating the state, with `wishlist[index].count++;` - that can get you troouble, but I think is not related to the warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that props of your component are changing (wishlist) component is rerendering and in this time `setLoading` is trying to update the state of the unmounted component. For this example, useEffect is not really useful.
The quickest solution is to keep the loading state in redux store as well and remove `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);` from this component.
Also, it worth mentioning, that it's better to decompose presentation and API interaction. I can recommend you two simple approaches for redux: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-api-middleware and https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk

Comment: I use thunk but for just testing, I removed this part and forgot to add them while adding code here:D. Warning remains same. What do you mean by unmounted component? I dont think that anyting unmounts. And is there any solution to use this component with useState?Thanks for reply

Comment: got it. In this case, simple fix is to remove state, create setLoading dispatch, and keep isLoading in redux store

Comment: Is there a reason why can't I use useState in this case?

Comment: well, I would say in this case it make sense to keep everything in one place. Either state or redux store. It will be more clear from the data-flow perspective. If there is some particular case to use useState here, you should use something like useEffect(() => setLoading(false), [props. wishlist]). But it rather a workaround.